# Accept any proceeding characters after specified state URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I'm using `ui-router` and one of my states URL can be appended with a dynamic key. So the state looks like this:

```
.state('reset-password', {
    url: '/reset-password/{.*}',
    template: require('html-loader!./features/forgot-password/html/reset-password.tpl.htm'),
    controller: 'ResetPasswordController',
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
})
```

But the URL could possibly be `/reset-password/134042?emailAddress=email@email.com`.

However if this is entered, the state is not recognised, and it defaults by loading the `/login` state:

```
$urlRouterProvider 
    .otherwise("/login")
```

**Question**

How do I allow any proceeding dynamic URL after `/reset-password`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the trailing part of a URL to match a state then you can use either of the following (equivalent) syntaxes:

- `/reset-password/{path:.*}`
- `/reset-password/*path`

The common thing to note is that the trailing part is bound to a name (i.e. `path`).

You should then be able to access that via `$stateParams` in your controllers.

Alternatively, if you want to let `ui-router` do more of the heavy lifting of parsing out URL parameters, you can do that too.

Included some approaches below:

```js
angular
  .module('app', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state({
        name: 'reset-password1',
        url: '/reset-password1/*path',
        controller: function ($stateParams) {
          this.path = $stateParams.path;
        },
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        template: '<pre>path={{$ctrl.path}}</pre>'
      })
      .state({
        name: 'reset-password2',
        url: '/reset-password2/:id?email',
        controller: function ($stateParams) {
          this.id = $stateParams.id;
          this.email = $stateParams.email;
        },
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        template: '<pre>id={{$ctrl.id}} email={{$ctrl.email}}</pre>'
      });
  });
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
  <a ui-sref="reset-password1({ path: '134042?email=email@email.com' })" ui-sref-active="active">Reset Password (1)</a>
  <a ui-sref="reset-password2({ id: 134042, email: 'email@email.com' })" ui-sref-active="active">Reset Password (2)</a>
  <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.28/angular-ui-router.min.js "></script>
```